What is it called when two things both have to happen first?
There is something in architecture and construction that is termed "build-ability." I am an architect and builder - it is not that unusual for a clever client to play architect and improve upon my recommendation, sometimes because of input from someone that is in the design field like a structural engineer but not an architect or builder. They figure/clever something up and sketch it and it looks like something real but they are myopically focused on one or two aspects at the expense of the desired big picture result. They solve those one or two things brilliantly but for the fact it is not possible to do a good job that will last because two things need to happen first to work even kind of OK.
We're building a round water tank tower airbnb - it is high off the ground. It will have a catwalk around it - I would build the tank so all the water runs off and there are minimum, well-detailed penetrations for stopping water intrusion. The two clever folks want to use the cat walk for scaffolding to work on the tower so they want to build the deck and hang the catwalk structure off of that, then traditionally frame the first floor and upper deck separately (I proposed balloon framing for this particular job rather than stacking). To stabilize the floor joists so they don't roll there should be a rim joist - in this case made of plywood so it will conform to the round form. That same rim joist should be part of the sheathing that ties the decking and wall framing together but that can't happen until after the walls are framed and also the catwalk structure will be in the way of sheathing the outside of the framing correctly. And incidentally after that it will be hard to put the siding on to where there won't be innumerable potential water intrusion points. It would be better to build the tank then cut slots and feed the catwalk structure through them for fastening but then it could not be used for scaffolding. We could double the plywood at the rim joist and extend it up to join the framing but that still leaves the siding added later with very likely water/rot problems done the way (in about five years it will begin to manifest).
In this case it is not he horse or cart that is first but the horse is in the cart or it is the horse carrying the cart. If only Mensa had a place for Dunning Kruger award winners - far from me. Any ideas?

Is your point that the proposed design is too clever? Or is it that you would need to both do A before B and also do B before A?

In computer code, that's a deadly embrace.

Holy wars aside, this sounds like what I've heard people in engineering call a catch-22 problem.

Does this answer your question? What is the term for a situation where you need to do first in order to do second, but to do first you need to do second? [A] Catch-22 [situation] is the usual term, as Conrado correctly puts in a comment.

If you dropped all of the first paragraph in that exposition, what would be lost, please?

Would 'simultaneously' not work?

In engineering context, you will find causality used to refer to the constraint that systems that you actually build can only act on past input (while idealized systems and analyses can and often do look into the future)

We use the cart before the horse metaphor when things are being done in the wrong order (sometimes, when attention is being focused on a minor detail rather than on the primary objective / subject).
When the problem is that two different things both have to happen first, we call it a chicken and egg situation / problem. This same metaphor can be used when we're trying to figure out what came first in the past and (less commonly) when trying to decide which to do first in the future. Or when acknowledging the impossibility of progress, if they must both come "first" because each requires the prior existence of the other, and they can't happen simultaneously.

I used the chicken and egg phrase. But it is not which comes first, but that they both have to come first. I wrote down all the answers - going to look up deadly embrace. Thank you.

"deadly embrace" (or "deadlock") and "race condition" are different usages. They normally refer to situations where software "locks up" because multiple programs want to use the same combination of resources, and access rights to different elements within the total combination have been granted to processes that refuse to relinquish what they've already got, but they can't continue without other resources that are being held by other processes. So they're about the paradox of getting out of a "stuck" process, whereas "chicken and egg" is about not being able to even start the process.

It's also a kind of deadlock: step A depends on step B, but step B depends on step A.

I only encounter "deadlock" in the context of two processes where both have obtained an "exclusive lock" on some resource, but neither can complete their task because they also need the resource locked by the other process, which won't relinquish it. The system "locks up" because each process ends up waiting forever for the other process to finish and free up the resources. Not really the same as a "chicken and egg" situation where there's only one process, which can't start at all because every possible "initial step" requires some other initial step to have already completed.

Maybe dreadlocked - a kind of high of being myopically focused on a detail while missing the big picture which is being able to build it and have it last.

As opposed to simultaneously - that is that needs to happen kind, but they are "mutually exclusive" because both need to happen first. The first paragraph was setting up the scenerio for how the question came into being - I'm new to this. I have observed the phenom before, I thought I would ask for a term to describe.

@dragonbreathe: Is that "dreadlocked" from smokin' ganja? (The Jamaican version of couch-lock :)

@FumbleFingers - yes as in so focused on getting icecream and remembering the other things to get like Doritos to crush on top of it you climb into the back seat of your car and wonder where the steering wheel is. Before you die try - Elle Este Tout Pour Lui by Axelle Red - not the acoustic version. Best song I've ever heard. I DJ for community radio.

I like it! Not quite The Flaming Lips - In The Arms Of Cocaine, though! :)
